# Entity framework call stored procedure with parametr

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, dbset

I need get list of class properies.

Code fragment:

```
DbSet<SomeClass> query = context.SomeClass;    

public partial class SomeClass
{
   public decimal ID { get; set; }
   public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

I need get `List<ModelName>`, but I cannot to do this. How I can get `List<ModelName>`?
I want anybody: context.MyStoreadProcedure(SomeClass);

I have another question. How implement call stored procedure where parametr is 
"SomeClass"?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.SomeClass.Select(sc=>sc.ModelName).ToList()
```

Comment: Sorry, I havent namespace using System.Linq;. I'm added now